# MySQL Query to Return Values Not in Database

Tags: mysql

I am working on a project to assist attendees who are attending specific conferences. I am working on a query to obtain the events in the conference as well as whether the specified user is attending or not attending this event. In order to keep track of whether the user is attending an event, we have a join table (Events_Users), so I'm not sure how to accomplish my task. I need to be able to SELECT all of the information for events and return that, along with an extra column "isAttending" (which is not present in the database) specifying whether that user is attending that conference or not.

I'd like the return result to be something like:

```
| event.id | isAttending |
|     1    |      1      |
|     2    |      0      |
|     3    |      0      |
```

Is this possible? (The userId will be passed in so I can check with that to determine if 'isAttending' is true or false).

As a side note, we have already tried making two separate calls (getAllEvents and isUserAttending); however, because these calls are asynchronous we are having trouble getting the information we want (I'm unaware of the details).

Thank you!

Comment: This can be accomplished using a `LEFT JOIN`. You need to show us a table structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have these tables

```
Events : id , other columns
Event_Users : event_id , user_id
Users : id , username
```

Here is the query whichi will give you idea. If null comes set value to 0 else 1 with IFNULL.

```
SELECT
  e.id,
  IFNULL(u.username,0,1) as isAttending
from `Events` as e
  LEFT JOIN Events_Users as eu ON eu.events_id = e.id
  LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = eu.user_id
where u.id = 1
```

where 1 is the SPECIFIC user id which you can replace dynamically